# Distinguish app state from status codes returned by requests

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a react redux app. The app state structure looks like this:

```
{
   groups: {gid1: group1, gid2: group2, ....},
   expenses: {eid1: expense1, eid2: expense2, ...}, 
   //.... the rest
}
```

My components make ajax calls to the backend (done in the action creators), and the response is handled by the reducer to update the state, which is then passed to the components.

For example, for creating a group, I have the following pieces of code:

```
export function createGroup(values, callback) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios.post(GROUP_ENDPOINT,
      {
        name: values.name,
        description: values.description
      }, AUTHORIZATION_HEADER)
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch(groupCreated(response.data));
      });
    };
}
```

action creator:

```
export function groupCreated(group) {
  return {
    type: CREATE_GROUP,
    payload: group
  }
}
```

reducer:

```
export default function(state=INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case CREATE_GROUP:
      return { ...state, [action.payload.id]: action.payload};
    default: 
      return state;
  }
}
```

The component:

```
class NewGroup extends Component {

  _onSubmit(values) {
    const { history } = this.props;
    this.props.createGroup(values, ({status}) => history.push('/group'));
  }

  _onCancel() {
    const { history } = this.props;
    history.push('/group');
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this._onSubmit.bind(this))}>
          {_.map(FIELDS, renderField.bind(this))}
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
          <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this._onCancel.bind(this)}>Cancel</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
  validate,
  //a unique id for this form
  form:'NewGroup',
  fields: _.keys(FIELDS),
  fields_def: FIELDS
})(
  connect(null, { createGroup })(NewGroup)
);
```

(the fact that this is a `redux-form` is not my concern right now. My question is generally about handling the situation while using react and redux)

This goes all well if the answer the backend responds successfully.

I'm wondering how should I handle different responses from the backend, for example if the response is not 200, where how with my app state should I notify the component that there's something wrong ? should I even incorporate the response status in my app state?

Answer (score 0):

With `redux-form` I wouldn't do that. Redux-form allows you to return a Promise from the onSubmit function. If this promise rejects with a SubmissionError you can handle the form rendering accordingly. Redux-form will set the `submitting` prop to true while the promise isn't resolved or rejected. You just need to take care to return a promise from the actioncreator (this can be done with a redux-middleware).

Comment: Actually this was just an example component. My question was regarding the general approach while using react and redux.

Comment: Common practice, you would have four actions, per async action. <ACTION>, <ACTION_LOADING>,<ACTION_SUCCESS>,<ACTION_FAILED>. This allows you to do pretty much what you want (to reduce or not).  These actions are triggered by the the async function. It's pretty nice to handle the side-effects with a middleware solution like `redux-saga`, you could write a single saga to handle all your fetches (using the logic I just described)

Comment: What if we want to only use the app state to talk back to the component, and not using callbacks (which is not a good practice in redux)
(I'm using `redux-thunk`, which I think should be doing the same thing as `saga`)

Comment: callbacks are no problem for `redux`, it depends on how you use them, but let's not get into that issue right now. The flow of your thunk would look something like (pseudo): 
dispatch(ACTION_LOADING)
fetch().then(dispatch(ACTION_SUCCESS).catch(dispatch(ACTION_FAILED)). This allows your reducer to reduce the state you want. Just add a `resource` prop or something to your action and you have a generic solution.

Comment: let's assume that for creating a group, I update the state of the app by adding the new group to the map of groups (I explained in the question how the app state structure look like). If a new group fails being added, how should the app state look like, to notify the UI that it failed being added ? I didn't get this in your suggestion.

Comment: consider adding gid3: 
after reducing ACTION_LOADING => groups: {gid1: group1, gid2: group2, gid3: {loading:true}....},
after reducing ACTION_SUCCESS => groups: {gid1: group1, gid2: group2, gid3: group3....},
after reducing ACTION_FAILED => groups: {gid1: group1, gid2: group2, gid3: {failed:true, reason:"unauthorized"}....},

But it's really up to you. Designing the state is a developer thing and should not be taken light.